# Variable is not getting iterated

Tags: javascript, variables

I've made a simple simple slider and right now i've reached a problem with my variable

I've realized that after every "forward" button tap, "clicks" variable increases only to 1,it is never getting greater.I was trying to use a for statement but it also did not worked.I would be very grateful if anybody could tell me where's the mistake.

Cheers

Here's my JS code

```
const fw = document.querySelector(".test-button_forward");
const back = document.querySelector(".test-button_backwards");
const img1 = document.querySelector('.images_first.active');
const img2 = document.querySelector(".images_second");
const img3 = document.querySelector(".images_third");

let clicks = 0;


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        console.log(clicks);

        fw.addEventListener('click', function() {
            for (clicks = 0; clicks < 2; clicks++) {
                if (clicks = 1) {
                    console.log(clicks);

                    img1.classList.remove('active');
                    img1.classList.add('hidden');

                    img2.classList.remove('hidden');
                    img2.classList.add("active");

                    console.log(clicks);
                    clicks = clicks + 1;

                } else if (clicks = 2) {
                    img2.classList.remove('active');
                    img2.classList.add("hidden");

                    img3.classList.remove('hidden');
                    img3.classList.add('active');

                    console.log(clicks);
                }
            }
        })
    }
)
```

[Link to slider](https://jsfiddle.net/bcztk9o8/1/)

Comment: if (clicks = 1)

Comment: get yourself a linting tool built into an IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
if (clicks = 1) {
```

you are setting clicks equal to one when you meant to check if it **is** equal. So instead do:

```
if (clicks === 1) {
```

I think that is the problem you are dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer OP. I went ahead and made some changes that might simplify things a little https://jsbin.com/munulakehu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to 2 you need to change your loop:

```
for (clicks = 0; clicks <= 2; clicks++)
```

and don't SET clicks to 1:

```
if (clicks === 1) {
```